# Iterate through a list without using a loop

Tags: python, list

I am currently working on a zabbix script to add users with their groups. One user has many groups and the [zabbix documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/api/reference/user/create) has the section as:

```
"usrgrps": [
            { "usrgrpid": "7" },
            { "usrgrpid": "8" },
            { "usrgrpid": "9" }
           ]
```

I have a list of group ids that I want to replace in the place of `7,8,9` with `list[0], list[1], list[2]`

I have tried using `.join` method:

```
mylist = ['12','13','14']
z =  '"usrgrpid":"'.join(mylist)
s = '"usrgrps": [{"%s"},]' % (z)
```

Output:

```
'"usrgrps": [{"12"usrgrpid":"13"usrgrpid":"14"},]'
```

Comment: Do you have a list or a string? Can't see why `str.join` is being used here.

Comment: To join the list in the string. I can use string because I am enclosing it in json.dumps before sending it out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension.

```
mylist = ['12', '13', '14']
d = {"usrgrps": [{'usrgrpid': uid} for uid in mylist]}
>>> d
{'usrgrps': [{'usrgrpid': '12'}, {'usrgrpid': '13'}, {'usrgrpid': '14'}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just build the data like this:

```
s = '"usrgrps": [{}]'.format(",".join(map(lambda x: '{{"usrgrpid":"{}"}}'.format(x), mylist)))

>>> s
'"usrgrps": [{"usrgrpid":"12"},{"usrgrpid":"13"},{"usrgrpid":"14"}]'
```

Lets expand what we are doing here:
We build a list of strings like `{"usrgrpid":"12"}`

```
map(lambda x: '"usrgrpid":{}"'.format(x), mylist)
```

Then we just make them separate by `,` with `",".join` to obtain a string like `{"usrgrpid":"12"},{"usrgrpid":"13"},{"usrgrpid":"14"}`

Finally just format the `"usrgrps": [{}]` string to inyect the previous string into the "list".

Otherwise you would need to work with the `json` python library:

```
import json
data = json.dumps({"usrgrps": [{'usrgrpid': uid} for uid in mylist]})
data
'{"usrgrps": [{"usrgrpid": "12"}, {"usrgrpid": "13"}, {"usrgrpid": "14"}]}'
```

Comment: @StefanPochmann, after saying so, maybe you shold say what is really wrong :)

Comment: well pointed thanks @StefanPochmann. Remember, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wg4trPZFUwc. PS: I got this once too haha

Answer (score 1):

```
ids=['12','13','14']    
{'usrgrps': list(map(lambda x: {'usrgrpid' : x}, ids))}
```